# Django: Column does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So I just pushed an update to the web server and did `makemigrations` then `migrate` and everything seems ok, then when I refresh the website page I got this error

**Traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://0.0.0.0/

Django Version: 2.0.2
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'HomePage',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'Cart']

Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/django/LovelyMemory/HomePage/templates/HomePage/base.html,                 error at line 8
   column HomePage_product.category_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "HomePage_product"."id", "HomePage_product"."category...
                                    ^

   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   3 : <html lang="en">
   4 : 
   5 : <head>
   6 :     <meta charset="utf-8">
   7 :     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   8 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width =device-width, initial-scale=     1">
   9 : 
   10 :     <title>{% block title %} Lovely Memory {% endblock %}</title>
   11 : 
   12 :     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static     'css/style.css' %}"/>
   13 :     <link     href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.1.1/minty/bootstrap.min.css    " rel="stylesheet"
   14 :           integrity="sha384-    4eGtnTOp6je5m6l1Zcp2WUGR9Y7kJZuAiD3Pk2GAW3uNRgHQSIqcrcAxBipzlbWP"     crossorigin="anonymous">
   15 :     <script defer     src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
   16 :     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   17 :       <script     src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
   18 :       <script     src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


Traceback:

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (column HomePage_product.category_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "HomePage_product"."id", "HomePage_product"."category...
                                    ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e,     request)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args,     **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/django/LovelyMemory/HomePage/views.py" in product_list
  25.     return render(request, 'HomePage/list.html', context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in     render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request,     using=using)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"     in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"     in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-        packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  168.             len_values = len(values)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  254.         self._fetch_all()

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1179.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  53.         results =     compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch,     chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1064.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False,     executor=self._execute)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from     exc_value

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: column HomePage_product.category_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "HomePage_product"."id", "HomePage_product"."category...
                                    ^
```

So I deleted all previous migrations and even `flush` the database and this error is still on

**My set up:**

Django (2.0.2)

gunicorn (19.7.1)

PostgreSQL

any thought on how to solve this?

this is the migration
[image: migration]

This is my migrations folder
[image: Folder]

Comment: Your `HomePage` app has not been migrated.

Comment: it has been migrated, I add a picture of the migrations @HåkenLid

Comment: Well now you've deleted all previous migrations, your systems are out of sync and it'll be very hard to recover. Why did you do that? Can you restore them from version control?

Comment: I have backups, I will restore it and see what happen @DanielRoseman

Comment: I restored the old version and add my new migration but still the same problem @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1):

Why do you create the migrations (makemigration) on the server and not in your local environment? Migrations should represent the history of your schema and should not be deleted in case of an error.
As Daniel Roseman said: Revover them and run them again. I hope you have a database backup.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this, so why I shouldn't create the `makemigrations` on the server?

Comment: Migrations are a vital part of the application. They are part of your applications source code and represent a state of the database schema.

So create them on a save environment, test them put them into the version control and deploy them. Then run the (tested) migrations in productive environment.

Comment: I did as you explained but it is still the same problem :(  @butterfly_princess

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you made new migrations and migrated them for Homepage? Because it seems your schema hasn't been updated yet and your `migrate` command did say it didn't apply any new migrations.

And, like butterfly_princess said, why did you update your server first? You should be updating the local environment first.

Comment: so I should do the `makemigrations` on my laptop then upload it to the server and then do the `migrate`?

Comment: Why not just `makemigrations` **and** `migrate` on your laptop first? And please make sure your migrations are actually being applied. When you run `migrate` it should say, for example:

`Applying Homepage.003_auto_20180629_0450... OK`

Comment: I tried this method but it seems like django doesn't see my new migration @Adam

Comment: That's weird. Your migrations are in the migrations folder of your app right?

Comment: Yeah I know and I have added my migration file to the question @Adam